# How to run Recurrent Neural Networks sample programs is tensorflow?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow in ubuntu using the following below commands

```sh
sudo apt-get install python2.7
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

After installing all the basic programs whatever given in tensorflow website is working fine. But I am able to run Recurrent Neural Networks sample programs (whatever pseudocode they had given) becoz i cam to know if we install it using the pip  **models/rnn/ptb** folder and also some others folder are missing. How to solve this?
          Later i came to know if we install it using the docker it installs all its dependencies. but having problems in docker installation also. whenevr i check (docker version command)it is showing, the following information

```sh
Client:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 17:43:42 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

How to resolve this?(I installed docker using the below commands

```sh
which wget
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
docker run hello-world (showing Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
))
```

How to solve this also?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about the ptb data, you have to download and install the data as described on this page (because we cannot distribute it with our install):

http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/index.html

Comment: k. that i've seen it already. my problem is docker is showing Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?. so i am not able to install tensorflow using docker

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your question is specific to Docker but I can tell you how I did it:

- cloned the git repository and compiled the tensorflow code from source
- generated installer using bazel and pip installed tensorflow
- build ptb_word_lm application, downloaded the data and ran the app as outlined in the link highlighted by @LudiMagister

seems to work and I get about 2k wps in terms of speed with GPU support. No idea if that's any good but it gives you a benchmark.

hope this helps.

Comment: if you don't mind could please explain step by step how you installed compiled and run the tensorflow of CPU version? and i tried with docker but it didn't work out and when i tried with bazel i am getting some errors.

Comment: @VinayKumar tbh I couldn't do it any better than what is already in the wiki https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#detailed_install if you have compilation errors it's best to post them on the exchange.